# Deploying war file to remote tomcat 8 using curl

Tags: tomcat, curl, deployment

From a remote machine A, I want to deploy a war to machine B running tomcat

I set the following in `tomcat-users.xml` on machine B

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

From machine A, I ran the following command

```
$ curl -T "test.war" "http://tomcat:tomcat@<machine b>:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/temp&update=true" -v
*   Trying machine B IP...
* Connected to (machine B IP) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'tomcat'
> PUT /manager/text/deploy?update=true HTTP/1.1
> Host: <machine b>:8080
> Authorization: Basic dG9tY2F0OnRvbWNhdA==
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 374778991
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Sun, 13 Aug 2017 00:12:37 GMT
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
<
* Closing connection 0
```

I tried opening the manager page 
`http:<machine b>8080/manager/html`, but it does not open. I am not sure if I am missing any configuration or the context path is incorrect.

Comment: What error do you get by opening the manager page?

Comment: I get a 404 not found

Comment: Can you access to `http://<machine b>:8080`?

Comment: yes, I can access it.

Comment: Is there the manager application in `webapps` directory with appropriate permission?

Comment: Actually, there is no manager directory in the webapps directory. I was given a package with a docker environment, so it could be that it is not present. Is it possible to add it? I want to remotely deploy war on it like above.

Comment: Your curl command works like a charm for me, I did not encounter any issues.
And @kosta if you are using the official tomcat docker container, you can get into the running container and you'll see a folder named webapp.dist which has all other apps, including the manager app.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by downloading tomcat6-admin on ubuntu and then copying the manager directory in the webapps folder of original tomcat 8.